# MySql #1005 Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Annoying MySQL error to create and altering table

```
MySQL said:
#1005 - Can't create table `school`.`exams` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2020-04-12 15:42:01 0x3a24 Error in foreign key constraint of table school/exams:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT `exams_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`exam_id`) REFERENCES `result` (`exam_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: The error says it all , I cannot clarify further,

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: For a start add both table defintions to the question.